# How to block search engines on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, web-crawler, robots.txt

How do you block search engine bots on a Google App Engine site? Is there an admin/config procedure, or are you supposed to use a normal robots.txt file- and if the latter, how do you get GAE to deliver a static file from the root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How abt this?

http://www.beaconhill.com/solutions/kb/appengine/add-robots-txt.html

Comment: PS- do you understand what the 'upload' directive is for? I'm looking at the documentation and it makes no sense to me- http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html

Comment: It tells what files are uploaded to the server on deployment.

Comment: Quote: This is necessary because the handler cannot determine which files in your application directory correspond with the given _url_ and _static_files_ patterns.